# pandas apply over a single column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a few columns in a dataframe read from a CSV file that appears to have a mix of `nan` and strings (that dataframe also has a few other columns are float with a few `nan` values as well), for example:

`[nan '12/31/1990 12:00:00 AM' '06/03/1991 12:00:00 AM'
 '09/15/1991 12:00:00 AM' '11/11/1991 12:00:00 AM']`

I am interested to convert this to

`[nan '12/31/1990' '06/03/1991'
 '09/15/1991' '11/11/1991']`

This question is in four parts:

suppose I want to convert the strings in the example above to remove the time, such as by using the function

`def rem_t_from_d(x): return x.split(sep = ' ')[0]`

1. I was thinking to convert the function above to handle the `nan` type (float) ? Would any missing value in a string column (when read from the CSV) be converted to `nan` (float) even if rest of the column in string?
2. how can I apply this function over a single column of pandas? In pandas documentation, the structure of the function is given as

   `DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds)`

but I don't see any ability to apply it to a column of the dataframe.

3. How can I check if an element in the dataframe is `nan`? The documentation [enter link description here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html) gave examples of how to check if there are `nan` in the whole column (e.g. using `.notnull()`) and how to assign an element to `nan` (e.g. using `= np.nan`), but not how to check. I tried using `np.isnan` to check for `nan`, but that seems to give me a type error.
4. also, in pandas, is there the equivalent of `NA_integer_` , `NA_real_`, `NA_character_`, `NA_complex_` like in R? such that an entire column can be designated as a string type if needed, instead of a mix of string and float?

I am using Python 3.4

Comment: 1. I'd just convert the columns to datetime and then access the date attribute, so `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).date` 2. You can apply to a series also but if you want to use the axis param then you can force a df with a single column using double sqaure brackets: `df[[col_name]].apply(func, axis=0)` 3. to check if an element is nan you can use the top-level `isnull` method so `pd.isnull(x)` will return True or False

Comment: It's unclear your 3rd question, are you asking how to replace nan values? You can use `fillna` or `replace` to do that. for question 4. you can do `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str)` to convert the column to str

Comment: thanks. didn't know the `astype` function. still a newbie to python

Comment: there is one issue though: `astype` converts the `nan` to a string `'nan'` rather than a `nan` of string type per se

Comment: You have to decide what to with the nan values, you can either drop them or convert them pre or post conversion, it's not that difficult, also generally on SO it should be 1 question per post